# HTTP cache control: no expire date

Tags: http, caching, http-headers

I've found some HTTP headers related to caching:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate
Expires: Fri, 30 Oct 1998 14:19:41 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 29 Jun 1998 02:28:12 GMT
```

I would like to set headers such that once the webpage is loaded it gets cached. It should expire after 24 hours, and if the browser wants to load it before it expires, it should load it from the cache (and not revalidate).

Answer (score 1):

to set your content to expire afer 24 hours the http-header should be

```
       Cache-Control: max-age=86400, must-revalidate
       Expires: Fri, 30 Oct 1998 14:19:41 GMT
       Last-Modified: Mon, 29 Jun 1998 02:28:12 GMT
```

The max-age tell the client that content is stale after 86400 seconds. must-revalidate tell the client to revalidate the content after expiration.

you can avoid `Expires` for `HTTP/1.1`, for HTTP/1.0 `Expire` header should be used.

refer to folowing linke for more details -

[must revalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006839/how-necessary-it-is-to-use-must-revalidate-in-cache-control-no-cache-must-r)

[max-age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932890/http-cache-control-max-age-must-revalidate)

[expire vs max-age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549177/expires-vs-max-age-which-one-takes-priority-if-both-are-declared-in-a-http-resp)